# How do I save a function that I want to frequently use?

Tags: mysql, function, duplicates, mariadb

Due to the nature of how I ingest data into my SQL database it's prone to duplicates so I have the following view:

```
SELECT IP, COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM ipdb
GROUP BY IP
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Current methodology is to then search for the offending duplicates and remove them one by one. It does require manual review because reasons, namely I have to determine the 'correct' or most up to date entry. Is there any way I can speed this up? Because lately what I've been doing is copying the offending IP into this query then deleting.

```
SELECT *
FROM ipdb
WHERE IP = '1.2.3.4'
AND IP IN (
    SELECT IP
    FROM ipdb
    GROUP BY IP
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
);
```

Comment: Can you add a unique key, preventing the duplicates?